# Does this illustration depict magnetic monopoles?

Tags: electromagnetism, applied-physics

This illustration 
[image]

appears in *Mechanical Design Of Electric Motors* (Tong 2014). Does it depict monopoles? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: Do *you* have any reason to expect this to depict a monopole? Why? (in technical texts, and as a rule of thumb, pictures depict only what text says they depict, and nothing else; does the text say anything about monopoles?)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: The reason I have to "expect" that it depicts two monopoles is the fact that one magnet is labeled exclusively as north and the other exclusively as south. Clearly given my knowledge of basic electromagnetism the term "expect" is a misnomer.

Comment: Magnetic monopoles are not seen experimentally yet.  The first magnet which shows north pole will have a south pole on it's interior side.

Answer (score 2):

The text is far from clear, but I think the writer is trying to say that a North pole and a South pole (displaced angularly by a few degrees) are part of the same (hidden) magnet, that runs parallel to the axis. [Another possibility would be for the magnets to run radially, so that at the left hand end there are hidden South poles closer to the axis, and at the right hand end there are hidden North poles closer to the axis, but I don't think the writer is saying this.] Whatever is the correct interpretation, it certainly isn't monopoles: they don't exist!